# How do I create an Ethereum HD wallet implementation with Nethereum

Tags: c#, blockchain, ethereum

I have been trying to create an HD wallet implementation in C# with Ethereum, so far the implementations I have seen are for smart contracts.
Below is a similar implementation in NBitcoin

```
ExtKey masterKey = ExtKey.Parse("***MasterKey***"); 
ExtPubKey masterPubKey = masterKey.Neuter();
ExtPubKey pubkey1 = masterPubKey.Derive((uint)id);
BitcoinAddress address = pubkey1.PubKey.GetAddress("****Bitcoin network type test or live****");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Nethereum for this.

Nethereum uses internally NBitcoin to derive the private and public keys, for more information on BIP32 check
       https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/key_generation/bip_32

Although Ethereum uses a different method to create their addresses and paths.

This sample below shows how to create an HD Wallet using BIP32 standard in Ethereum.

You can run this sample in the Nethereum playground http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1043

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;
using Nethereum.Util;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NBitcoin;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexConvertors.Extensions;
using Nethereum.HdWallet;

public class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Initiating a HD Wallet requires a list of words and an optional password to add further entropy (randomness)

        var words = "ripple scissors kick mammal hire column oak again sun offer wealth tomorrow wagon turn fatal";
        //Note: do not confuse the password with your Metamask password, Metamask password is used to secure the storage
        var password = "password";
        var wallet = new Wallet(words, password);

        // An HD Wallet is deterministic, it will derive the same number of addresses 
        // given the same seed (wordlist + optional password).

        // All the created accounts can be loaded in a Web3 instance and used as any other account, 
        // we can for instance check the balance of one of them:

        var account = new Wallet(words, password).GetAccount(0);
        Console.WriteLine("The account address is: " + account.Address);

        var web3 = new Web3(account, "http://testchain.nethereum.com:8545");
        //we connect to the Nethereum testchain which has already the account preconfigured with some Ether balance.
        var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(account.Address);
        Console.WriteLine("The account balance is: " + balance.Value);

        //Or transfer some Ether, as the account already has the private key required to sign the transactions.

        var toAddress = "0x13f022d72158410433cbd66f5dd8bf6d2d129924";
        var transactionReceipt = await web3.Eth.GetEtherTransferService()
            .TransferEtherAndWaitForReceiptAsync(toAddress, 2.11m, 2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Transaction {transactionReceipt.TransactionHash} for amount of 2.11 Ether completed");
    }
}
```